# How do we find the width of river?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> Two boats on opposite banks of a river start moving towards each
>   other. They first pass each other 1400 meters from one bank. They each
>   continue to the opposite bank, immediately turn around and start back
>   to the other bank. When they pass each other a second time, they are
>   600 meters from the other bank. We assume that each boat travels at a
>   constant speed all along the journey. Find the width of the river?

Answer is supposed to be 3600 meters. But how do I approach the problem ?

Comment: Start with a sketch then model the position functions. Translate the information from the text into proper equations. Solve.

Comment: https://www.theproblemsite.com/problems/high-school-math/2004/row-row-row  http://www.beatthegmat.com/boat-and-stream-t277140.html

Comment: how about the river has a width w, the boats have speeds s1 and s2 - come up with equations for how far they have travelled when they meet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $x$ be the width of the river. It is given that, when they have met the first time, boat$_1$ has travelled $1400$ m and boat$_2$, $(1400-x)$ metres.

When they meet for the second time, boat$_1$ has travelled $600+(x-1400) = (x-800)$ m, and boat$_2$, $1400 +(x-600) = (x+800)$ m.

Note that, *the relationship of the distances each traveled, is the same to both meetings*. Thus, $$\frac{1400}{1400-x} = \frac{x-800}{x+800}$$ $$\Rightarrow x= ?$$ Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: The solutions to the equation you provide are not in $\mathbb{R}$. I think it is because boat$_{1}$ did not travel $1400-x$ to the first meeting, it traveled $x-1400$. Similarly, to the second meeting the boats have traveled $x+600$ and $2x-600$ respectively. Using $1400$, $x-1400$, $x+600$ and $2x-600$ provides correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $m_1$ be the speed, in meters per second, of the fist boat and similarly for $m_2$. Let $s_{1}$ be the time, in seconds when they meet for the first time and $s_{2}$ be the time when they meet for the second time. Let $w$ be the width of the river. From your text, $s_1m_1+s_1m_2=w$ and $s_2m_1+s_2m_2=3w$. Assuming 'one bank' is the one from which boat $1$ started, you also know $s_1m_1=1400$ and $s_2m_1=w+600$. You can do the rest.